# Add product from database in PHP SQL and show using Bootstrap grid system

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add products dynamically from SQL database and using Bootstrap here but it shows my product on next line even if I am not using row the same result shown.

Here is my code and output.

```
include ("connection.php");
$sql = "select * from products";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="<?php  echo $row['Pimage'] ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php  echo $row['Pname'] ?></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php  echo $row['Pdesc'] ?></p>
                        <P><?php  echo $row['Pprice'] ?>PKR</P>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">ADD To Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: `col-lg-12` means a single, full page column.  Maybe you want 3x columns, so use `col-lg-4`.  I suggest starting with some Bootstrap tutorials, or even just [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/), they are quite good.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php    
    include ("connection.php");
    $sql = "select * from products";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="<?php  echo $row['Pimage'] ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php  echo $row['Pname'] ?></h5>
                <p class="card-text"><?php  echo $row['Pdesc'] ?></p>
                <P><?php  echo $row['Pprice'] ?>PKR</P>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">ADD To Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

In that way you will have 4 columns of products